# Populate array with javascript objects. Objects chosen by comparing two String values

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an object which looks like the following:

```
parentObj:{

    nodes: [
        {
            nodeId : 'AAA',
            nodeType : 'bottom'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'BBB',
            nodeType : 'top'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'CCC',
            nodeType : 'bottom'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'DDD',
            nodeType : 'top'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'EEE',
            nodeType : 'bottom'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'FFF',
            nodeType : 'middle'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'GGG',
            nodeType : 'middle'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'HHH',
            nodeType : 'bottom'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'III',
            nodeType : 'middle'
        }
    ],

    owners: {
        'Johnson' : [ 'AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD', 'III' ], /* node ids to indicate Johnson owns these nodes */
        'Smith' : [ 'XXX', 'GGG', 'EEE', 'FFF' ] /* node ids to indicate Smith owns these nodes */
    }

}
```

What I would like to do is write a function which passes in an owner name and a node type and which would output an array of nodes which belong to that owner and also match the specified node type.

For example,

```
var getNodes = function('Johnson', 'top'){
    var ret;

    /* some logic I've yet to understand... */

    return ret;
}


/* ret would look like this */

ret = [

        {
            nodeId : 'BBB',
            nodeType : 'top'
        },
        {
            nodeId : 'DDD',
            nodeType : 'top'
        }
]
```

So only the nodes which belonged to `Johnson` and were of type `top` populate my array.

I'd preferably like to use underscore to accomplish this if at all possible?

Would anyone have any suggestions or advice?

Comment: I'm sure the downvote is justified, but an explanation would help me with future questions

Comment: Quite simple: It all looks like you haven't tried anything before posting the question.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko ah I see. Well the opposite is very much true, but I tried to keep the question as clean and tidy as I could. Thanks for the explanation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getNodes(ownerName, nodeType){
    return _.chain(parentObj.nodes)
            .filter(function(d){ 
                return _.contains(parentObj['owners'][ownerName], d.nodeId);
            })
            .where({'nodeType': nodeType})
            .value();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var name = "Johnson";
var type = "top"; 
var getNodes = function( name, type ){
    var ret = [];
    var nodes = parentObj.owners[name];
    for ( var counter = 0; counter < parentObj.nodes.length; counter++ )
    {
       if ( nodes.indexOf( parentObj.nodes[ counter ].nodeId ) != -1  && parentObj.nodes[ counter ].nodeType == type )
       {
           ret.push( parentObj.nodes[ counter ] );
       }
    }

    return ret;
}; 
console.log(getNodes( name, type ));
```

Comment: that code has bugs falling all over the place ... :|

Comment: bug on last line ... console.leg(ret) ... the interpreter will tell you that ret is not defined.

Comment: @Aukhan did you ran the code? anyways using the returned value now.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to do with underscore using the _.filter method
You could do something like

```
var ret=_.filter(parentObj,function(val){return val.nodeType=="top"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to build owned items cache by owner and `filter` to actually filter the nodes list.

```
function getNodes(owner, type) {
   var belongsToOwner = data.owners[owner].reduce(function(acc, name){ 
      return acc[name] = 1, acc;
   }); 

   return data.nodes.filter(function(node) {
      return node.nodeType === type && belongsToOwner[node.nodeId]
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work:

```
var getNodes = function(owner, position){
    var ret=[];
    var nodes = parentOb.owners[owner];
    _.each(nodes, function(node){
        ret = ret.concat(_.findWhere(parentObj.nodes, {"nodeId": node.nodeId, "nodeType": position}));
    })

    return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that using filter could solve your problem.

```
var getNodes = function(name, type){
    var ret = _.filter(parentObj.nodes, function(node) {
        return node.nodeType === type && _.contains(parentObj.owners[name], node.nodeId
    }

    return _.uniq(ret);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This proposal iterates over the object an returns an array with the wanted result.

```js
function getNodes(owner, nodeType) {
    return data.parentObj.nodes.filter(function (a) {
        return a.nodeType === nodeType && ~data.parentObj.owners[owner].indexOf(a.nodeId);
    });
}

var data = { parentObj: { nodes: [{ nodeId: 'AAA', nodeType: 'bottom' }, { nodeId: 'BBB', nodeType: 'top' }, { nodeId: 'CCC', nodeType: 'bottom' }, { nodeId: 'DDD', nodeType: 'top' }, { nodeId: 'EEE', nodeType: 'bottom' }, { nodeId: 'FFF', nodeType: 'middle' }, { nodeId: 'GGG', nodeType: 'middle' }, { nodeId: 'HHH', nodeType: 'bottom' }, { nodeId: 'III', nodeType: 'middle' }], owners: { 'Johnson': ['AAA', 'BBB', 'DDD', 'III'], 'Smith': ['XXX', 'GGG', 'EEE', 'FFF'] } } },
    result = getNodes('Johnson', 'top');

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```